# Rotation Algorithim

Tags: combinatorics

I have a series of 7 tables and 73 participants in a roundtable discussion. My challenge is to rotate all 73 participants to each of the 7 tables while minimizing the times in which they sit with the same person. The tables have a maximum seating capacity of 11. I am looking for a schedule (spreadsheet) that shows the rotation schedule of each person. Thank you.